# Data is being lost on map function

Tags: reactjs

Hello there  hope you are doing well! I'm new to react and was trying to make a simple online store to learn and right now I'm managing the functionality from removing from the cart and I have the following:

```
return data.map(value => {return <Card>
        <Card.Content>
            <Card.Header>{value.ProductName}</Card.Header>
            <Card.Meta>Price: {value.ProductPrice}</Card.Meta>
            <Card.Description>
                Quantity: {value.ProductQuantity}
            </Card.Description>
        </Card.Content>
        <Card.Content extra>
            <form onSubmit={handleDelete}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="quantity_to_be_removed">Quantity to be removed: </label>
                    <input name="quantity_to_be_removed" type="number" defaultValue="1" min="1" max={value.ProductQuantity}
                    ref={quantityToBeRemovedRef}/>
                    <label htmlFor="cart_id" />
                    <input name="cart_id" type="hidden" value={value.CartId} ref={cartIDRef}/>
                    <label htmlFor="product_id"/>
                    <input name="product_id" type="hidden" value={value.ProductId} ref={productIDRef}/>
                </div>
                <Button type="submit" basic color='red'>
                    Remove From Cart
                </Button>
            </form>
        </Card.Content>
    </Card>});
```

And it looks like this:

[image: Front End Sample]

I have set up so the db asks for the cart id, the product id and the quantity to be removed thus the quantity to be removed is fetched from the quantity_to_be_removed input, and I added the cart id and product id as hidden inputs. The idea was that in the loop where everythig is rendered each cart would have the id of the product is displaying, the cart id and the quantity to be removed to query the database but right now it only works if I click on the last item:

[image: Removing last element Console log example]

If I click in any other item I get the data from the last element if it hasn't been removed or this:

[image: Null Reference Sample]

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated, thanks and have a great day!

PS. not sure if it helps but the db is configured in postgres sql and the request are made through axios.

Refs:
[image]

Db call:
[image]

Comment: For one, you're missing the `key` prop required for arrayed JSX elements: `<Card>` should be `<Card key={value.CartId}>` (assuming `CartId` is unique).

Comment: Secondly: You aren't showing what you're doing with `quantityToBeRemovedRef` (or the other refs). Right now you're assigning the same ref to multiple elements as the loop is iterated, which sounds like the source of your bug.

Comment: Which specific line in the code shown produces the error?  Which specific object is `null`?  What do you expect that object to be?  Why?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hi AKX thanks for responding so quickly I created three different ref and I use them to make a call back to the db

Comment: Any reason use a form, and not simply bind the arguments to your handleDelete method instead?